# PostgreSQL: increasing a column's length in a very large table

Tags: postgresql

Aurora PostgreSQL, version 10.4.

I have a table with several million rows. One of the columns is defined as `character varying(255)`. Once upon a time, 255 was plenty of room, but now it's not, so I have to make more.

I found this [in the PG 9.1 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/release-9-1.html):

> - Allow ALTER TABLE ... SET DATA TYPE to avoid table rewrites in appropriate cases (Noah Misch, Robert Haas)
>
> For example, converting a varchar column to text no longer requires a rewrite of the table. However, increasing the length constraint on a varchar column still requires a table rewrite.

This suggests that changing to a longer `varchar` is not practical (since rewriting a table of that size would lock it for an ungodly amount of time), but changing to `text` would work. Is this correct?

Any other things I should know about when making such a change? I want to avoid data loss, obviously, and I can't afford to make this table inaccessible for more than a short period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have read all release notes.

Because just [one version later](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/release-9-2.html#AEN114949)

> Increasing the length limit for a varchar or varbit column, or removing the limit altogether, no longer requires a table rewrite.

You can test that easily for yourself:

```
postgres=# select version();
                          version
------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# \timing on
Timing is on.
postgres=# create table alter_test (id serial, some_col varchar(255));
CREATE TABLE
Time: 22.331 ms
postgres=# insert into alter_test (some_col) select md5(random()::text) from generate_series(1,10e6);
INSERT 0 10000000
Time: 40894.275 ms (00:40.894)
postgres=# alter table alter_test alter column some_col type varchar(500);
ALTER TABLE
Time: 5.297 ms
postgres=#
```

Comment: I just tried increasing the VARCHAR length, and it didn't work. The table became inaccessible. I killed the command after about 2 minutes.

Comment: What else could be causing this? I know there aren't any indexes on this column.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak: an `alter table` requires an exclusive lock on the table which it can't get. You probably have other transactions accessing that table. Look for session that are `idle in transaction` (or `active`) in `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: If there's an AFTER UPDATE trigger on the table, would it be set off by this operation?

Comment: I figured it out. There was a view that was referencing this column. After I dropped the view, it worked. Thanks again for your help.